# GMSReverseGeocodeResponse returns all results with missing addresses

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

For the last 48 hours, the `GMSReverseGeocoder` on Google maps iOS SDK (latest version 2.7) returns results with missing addresses in areas with latitude and longitude that used to work properly. One example is:

```
GMSAddress {
coordinate: (37.915000, 23.730000)
lines: Alimos, Greece
subLocality: Alimos
locality: South Athens
administrativeArea: Decentralized Administration of Attica
country: Greece
}
```

`Lines` should contain the whole address but now it contains only the sublocality and the country. The issue is that it works properly for a couple of hours and then it returns to these kind of results and it never returns an error so I can use a fallback mechanism for reverse geocoding. (The results of this can be seen in popular apps like Lyft that rely on Google Maps iOS SDK for reverse geocoding).

Has anyone found a solution on how to overcome this? There is no api change in the geocoder in the latest updates.

PS. For the same lat/long, Google Maps Web Api and Android Api return fine results.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @fabiomartins87 No solution yet, google has acknowledged the issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/78809393

Comment: This should be resolved now per Google at that issue tracker link:  
As of 2018-04-30 17:44 PDT, the rollout of the fix has been declared complete, and the issue should be resolved for all affected users. We will conduct an internal investigation of this issue and make appropriate improvements to our systems to help prevent or minimize future recurrence.

Comment: Yes it seems shorted out